# Why is the failbit being set. File seems to have printed fine

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that does the work it is intended to do but I have doubts about failbit. Th catch block always runs although the file is displayed on the screen. When eof is reached why is failbit set? Maybe I am not understanding the right meaning of failbit..Has something failed?

```
    int main()
    {
        ifstream infile;
        char c;
        infile.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit );

        try
        {
            infile.open("../Dose.c", ios::in);
            while (!infile.eof())
            {   
                c=infile.get();
                cout << c;
            }
            infile.close();

        }
        catch(ifstream::failure e)
        {
            cout << infile.eof() << " " << infile.fail() << " " << infile.bad() << " " << infile.good() ; 
            cerr << " Exception opening/reading/closing file\n";
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

The OUTPUT: 1 1 0 0 Exception opening/reading/closing file. So clearly fail() and eof is set.

Comment: FWIW, `ios::in` is unnecessary, the loop should be `while (infile.get(c)) {cout << c;}`, `infile.close();` is unnecessary, `return 0;` is unnecessary, and exceptions should be caught by const reference.

Comment: What makes you think eof has been reached before failure? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

27.5.5.4, paragraph 7:

> bool eof() const;
>   Returns: true if eofbit is set in rdstate().

In other words, all that eof() does is check if eofbit is **already** set. It doesn't "actively" check if the end of file has been reached.

Skipping a bunch of dry, formal, specifications, what happens is that the end of file condition gets detected inside get(). eofbit gets set first, then failbit (the get() operation failed). Because you enabled exceptions, the act of setting the failbit throws an exception. If exceptions were not enabled, get() would return traits::eof(), typically -1, instead of the character read from the file.

Takeaway:

1. When using exceptions, eof()'s only value comes after the exception is already thrown, to determine whether the exception was due to an end of file condition. In your example, eof() will never return true.
2. When not using exceptions, eof() is not really needed, just check if get() returned -1.

Comment: All I was trying to do was to open the file with a try catch block. that was my intent. So that I could do some exception handling incase the file does not exist or some error occurs in opening it.

Comment: All you have to do is use is_open() to check if the file was opened succesfully.